# Memory Scan in c++

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, memory

I am working on a **WIN32 project** in **Visual Studio 2010**. I am trying to Scan my main memory through the ClamAV(open source antivirus) Engine for searching a malicious/infected file in main memory.

The code i have written so far creates a snapshot of the whole main memory by using the windows function *CreateToolhelp32Snapshot*

Then i open a specific process from the snapshot, and pass this to the ClamAV engine, the engine then decides whether it is malicious or not. and i repeat the whole mechanism after every 10seconds. But i think this is not an efficient way,

What i want to do is to scan my whole memory once, and after this i scan only those process which is newly created in the main memory. Kindly guide me is there any way to get newly created methods from the memory only and not the whole memory

Comment: I think it is not safe to only scan newly created processes since a previous 'clean' process may become a malicious one after you scanned it the first time.

Comment: I think this is not really possible, there a various kinds of memory. I would suggest to hook `VirtualAlloc`/`VirtualAllocEx` for this purpose, but this is not guarantee. What if a process has allocated several pages but write to this pages some time later. You can never know that.

Comment: you could store the previous processes in a data structure of your choice. if the process has the need of knowing the processes after a restart (of the application) you need to store it on the disk. this opens security doors and as mentioned by Naruil, code could be clean and then become malicious ...

Comment: I think you should write a driver that make the memory pages read-only once you have scanned it. And later you can check only the dirtied pages.

Comment: thanks for replying, well if this method is not guaranteed then what could be the possible way to make the memory scan efficient, or whether the file must be scan before loading into memory

Comment: @WiXXeY Scanning files is still not a solid way. For example, one may store malicious code inside a encrypted file. The file may later be loaded into memory,decrypted and executed. And you cannot detected it when it is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

I think it cannot be done purely in user space program.
I am not very familiar with Windows API but I can give you some rough hint on how to do it.

1. You should scan every program **BEFORE** it is executed.
2. Make all the memory a program allocated later **non-executable** (NX bit)
3. The program will trigger a page-fault when it try to execute it, scan it now !!
4. Make the scanned memory **read-only**, and then go on to execute it
5. Make it **non-executable** again once a program tries to write this area.

NOTE: If you want to ensure security, a memory area can **NEVER** become executable and writable at the same time.

In this way you need only check those memory being executed. And it should be very efficient.